# Flutter : OBD2 connectivity using wifi

Tags: flutter, dart, wifi, communication, obd-ii

I want to communicate with OBD2 from my Flutter App using wifi. But I don't know how to establish a connection using wifi and how to get information from OBD2.

Answer (score 2):

To communicate with a (generic serial) OBD2 adapter, you have to use a socket abstraction and implement a communication queue that allows to send commands, then receive and deliver the results asynchronously to the caller.

Default WiFi OBD2 adapters have a TCP server running at `192.168.0.10:35000` where you can communicate.

Comment: I don't know how to establish a connection with OBD in flutter. Is there any Plugin available for that?

Comment: I don't know anything about flutter. But as I said, it's a TCP connection, so you may want to try the network stack, in particular a socket abstraction.